# Accessing a variable using a string containing the variable's name

Tags: c#, string, variables, reflection

I am reading the name of a string variable from the database (e.g. "_datafile"). I want to know how I can access a named variable within my program using this string.

I have already tried using a dictionary, hash table, and a switch-case statement but I would like to have the variable resolve itself dynamically. Is this possible?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you show some code? How have you used a switch-case statement and a dictionary, and what do you mean by *resolve dynamically*?

Comment: What do you mean by `"_datafile" to become _datafile` ?

Comment: here is a code snippet along with the dictionary definition         while (rdr.Read())
            {
                string step = rdr.GetString(rdr.GetOrdinal("Step"));
                string tag = rdr.GetValue(rdr.GetOrdinal("Tag")).ToString();
                string value = rdr.GetValue(rdr.GetOrdinal("Value")).ToString();
                
                AddDataToWorkflow(step, tag, SearchDictionary(value));
                
            }

Answer (score 11):

Do you mean you want to get the value of a field using the field name as a string?

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string _datafile;

    public MyClass()
    {
        _datafile = "Hello";
    }

    public void PrintField()
    {
        var result = this.GetType().GetField("_datafile").GetValue(this); 
        Console.WriteLine(result); // will print Hello
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**  @Rick, to respond to your comment:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public IEnumerable<string> _parameters = new[] { "Val1", "Val2", "Val3" };

    public void PrintField()
    {
        var parameters = this.GetType().GetField("_parameters").GetValue(this) as IEnumerable;

        // Prints:
        // Val1
        // Val2
        // Val3
        foreach(var item in parameters)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this is partially working    public static string _dataFile;     string value = rdr.GetValue(rdr.GetOrdinal("Value")).ToString();   string result = this.GetType().GetField(value, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public).GetValue(this).ToString();    this works with singular variables, now I have to get it to work with a collection for example: a collection of data named _parameters I would be looking to resolve _parameters.From etc.

Comment: Does the edit above answer your question?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get the value of a field based on its string name you will have to use reflection.

```
class MyClass
{
    public int DataFile { get; set; }

    public int _datafile;
}

var ob = new MyClass();
var typ = typeof(MyClass);
var f = typ.GetField("_datafile");
var prop = typ.GetProperty("DataFile");
var val = f.GetValue(ob);
var propVal = prop.GetValue(ob);
```

Comment: I don't think that will work _as is_. `_datafile` needs to be a property.

Comment: You should be able to do the same thing with properties. I've added one to my example.

Comment: Hmm yeah, it will work with `DataFile`, but not with `_datafile`. You should remove `var f = typ.GetField("_datafile");`

Comment: This code works in LinqPad but only if the field is public, so I'd agree that normally you wouldn't want to access a field this way. It depends on what the OP is trying to do though.

Comment: Ok my mistake, I thought it only worked with properties and not with fields. But it does indeed.

Answer (score -1):

Usually you would create a class representing the values of one table record. If your table has an `ID` a `FirstName` and a `LastName` column, you would create a class like this

```
public class Person
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Then you create a list of persons

```
var people = new List<Person>();
```

Now you can add persons to the list.

```
var p = new Person();
p.ID = 5;
p.FirstName = "John";
p.LastName = "Doe";
people.Add(p);
```

---

You can use a DataReader in order to read from a table

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM tblPerson WHERE LastName LIKE @pattern";
cmd = new SqlCommand(sql);
cmd.Connection = "server=test;uid=sa;pwd=manager;database=northwind";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pattern", "A%"); // Names beginning with "A"
using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
    // Get column indexes
    int idOrdinal = reader.GetOrdinal("ID");
    int firstNameOrdinal = reader.GetOrdinal("FirstName");
    int lastNameOrdinal = reader.GetOrdinal("LastName");

    while(reader.Read()) {
        var p = new Person();
        p.ID = reader.GetInt32(idOrdinal);
        p.FirstName = reader.GetString(firstNameOrdinal);
        p.LastName = reader.GetString(lastNameOrdinal);
        people.Add(p);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear, but I think this question is actually about reflection, not database access...