# How can I put a variable in this part of my code?

Tags: c#

I have two examples

```
Primary.Teal800, Primary.Teal900, Primary.Teal500, Accent.LightGreen400, TextShade.WHITE
```

and

```
Convert.ToInt32(textBox.Text)
```

The part after the `.` I want a variable. For example, the pseudo-code for this would be

```
var color = "Teal";
Primary.color + 800, Primary.color + 900, Primary.color + 500, Accent.LightGreen400, TextShade.WHITE
```

or

```
var toWhich = "ToInt32";
Convert.toWhich(textBox.Text)
```

Would there be any way to do that?

I'm accessing an enum

Comment: What is first example? Array? Enum?

Comment: @Sinatr I'm using this code https://github.com/IgnaceMaes/MaterialSkin

Comment: This question is not clear. Are you saying you want to create a new color variable with the combinations above?

Comment: @ChibuezeOpata I had a typo, I changed the OP. Is that better? Instead of having to keep typing in `"Teal"` I would just put in the variable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing a variable using a string containing the variable's name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11122241/accessing-a-variable-using-a-string-containing-the-variables-name)

Comment: @Sayse He is accessing a field in an `enum`, not a variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `Primary` is an `enum`, you can use `Enum.Parse`. Make a helper method for it:

```
static Primary GetPrimaryColor(string name, int number) {
    return (Primary)Enum.Parse(typeof(Primary), name+number);
}
```

Calling the helper lets you do this:

```
var color = "Teal";
GetPrimaryColor(color, 800), GetPrimaryColor(color, 900), ...
```

Comment: @Sayse I followed the link in OP's comment to github, and found [this file](https://github.com/IgnaceMaes/MaterialSkin/blob/b130c6e8ba38143d8e5c890cf86dc83252959bb4/MaterialSkin/ColorScheme.cs).

Comment: Holy. You're awesome.

Comment: @Sayse see [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/jvl9a.png), from the Metadata.